# ASP.NET simple web site 'framework'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I'm a LOB .NET applications developer that would like to do some www consumer facing web site development for small business, along with internet marketing. Typically I need just a simple 5 page layout 'home', 'about us', 'contact', 'faq', etc... But with flexibility to expand onto it if needed.

I guess my question is - are there any ASP.NET frameworks that I could buy/use that would give me a head start and save me from writing the code myself? My requirements are as described above - but with each page data driven from MSSQL preferably with a login page for admins to update their site content...

I did searching on this; but all I found were ASP.NET code generators that would take a SQL database and generate pages based on the tables for CRUD/reporting purposes... This really isn't what I need.. It shouldn't take very long for me to make it myself; however if someone's already done the legwork I'd love to re-use their code if possible.

thanks

***EDIT: anyone know if there is something similar to what I'm looking for for ASP.NET MVC?***

***EDIT2: David has answered my question and I will be going with the small business sample from the asp.net website. I'd like to add another related question and not have to start a new thread: What framework would you recommend for a social networking website?? I really liked the 'club site starter kit'.... would this be a good starting point? Or are there better frameworks around then this? Maybe DotNetNuke?? Thanks again!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the starter kits here:
http://www.asp.net/community/projects/

Some of them are overkill for what you want, but all are good.  I'd look at the club or business starter kits first for what you're describing.  And the price is right. (free)

Although in all honesty , what you're describing can be done easily enough that a starter kit isn't even really necessary.  You're talking about simple content pages for the most part, and this can be done in pure html.

Comment: This is great. the small busines website template is exactly the thing I was looking for. I can build off of this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Web Platform might be interesting for you ( http://www.microsoft.com/web ) and specially a list of Content Management Systems at http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/Categories.aspx?category=ContentMgmt

Comment: thanks for the links. I'm wondering now if DotNetNuke is overkill for what I need or something worth pursueing. Anyone have any links to sample apps built with DotNetNuke? Is the 'show live sample' link on Davids aspnet link, it did not bring me to a sample website...

Comment: @dferraro, we're using DotNetNuke in one of our internal web sites.  IMHO it's overkill for your situation.  The learning curve is steepat first, but once you "get" the basics, then it's a breeze to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Might add [N2](http://n2cms.com/) cms to this list if you want something lightweight and are comfortable doing some coding.

There is a MVC version available I think.

Answer (score 0):

https://pagematic.org/

I think I'm answering a very old question. I have a system I've just started developing. Simple web pages and forms can be created. I keep improving. You may be interested.